# proving monad laws of a new monad instance (list of maybe)

Tags: haskell, monads

I made a new List of Maybe Monad instance and tried to prove the implementation does satisfy the Monad laws, am I doing it right or is the implementation incorrect? Any pointer is appreciated. Thanks!

```
newtype Test a = Test { getTest :: [Maybe a] }
  deriving Functor

instance Applicative Test where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = liftM2 ($)

instance Monad Test where
  return :: a -> Test a
  return a = Test $ [Just a]
  
  (>>=) :: Test a -> (a -> Test b) -> Test b
  Test [Nothing] >>= f = Test [Nothing]
  Test [Just x] >>= f = f x

{-
1. return x >>= f = f x
     return x >>= f = [Just x] >>= f = f x   
 
2. m >>= return = m
     [Nothing] >>= return = [Nothing]
     [Just x] >>= return = return x = [Just x] 

3. (m >>= f) >>= g    ==    m >>= (\x -> (f x >>= g))

   m = [Nothing]
   L.H.S. = ([Nothing] >>= f ) >>= g = Nothing >>= g = Nothing
   R.H.S. = [Nothing] >>= (\x -> (f x >>= g)) = Nothing
   m = [Just x]
   L.H.S. = ([Just x] >>= f) >>= g = f x >>= g
   R.H.S. = [Just x] >>= (\v -> (f v >>= g)) = (\v -> (f v >>= g)) x
          = f x >>= g
-}
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't finished defining it.  What is `Test [] >>= f` or `Test [Just x, Just y] >>= f`?

Comment: Enable warnings, they will report your pattern matching to be non-exhaustive. I didn't check your proofs, since you need to  fix your `>>=` before.

Comment: I read the Monad law proofs of the List Monad and noticed it used functions like concat and map, but it seems that I cannot use them in here. In that case, does that make the implementation significantly more difficult?

Comment: If you define `pure` directly, `return` has a default definition of `return = pure`, since `Applicative` is now a superclass of `Monad`. (Same amount of work, but fits with the modern Functor-Applicative-Monad hierarchy, rather than the old assumption that a `Monad` instance for a type already exists when it comes time to write an `Applicative` instance.)

Comment: You may find it easier to prove the monad laws in terms of monadic *composition* (`(>=>) :: (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c` / `(<=<) = flip (>=>)`) rather than application (`>>=` / `=<<`), since then they’re phrased more symmetrically: 1. **left identity** `return >=> x` = `x`; 2. **right identity** `x >=> return` = `x`; and 3. **associativity** `(x >=> y) >=> z` = `x >=> (y >=> z)`. This also more clearly shows their relationship to the `Monoid`, `Alternative`, and `Category` laws.

Answer (score 0):

The bits of the proof you have written are only incorrect in unimportant ways. Specifically, in these two lines:

```
([Nothing] >>= f ) >>= g = Nothing >>= g = Nothing
[Nothing] >>= (\x -> (f x >>= g)) = Nothing
```

The three bare `Nothing`s should be `[Nothing]`s.

However, the proof is incomplete, because there are values of type `Test a` that are neither of the form `[Just (x :: a)]` nor `[Nothing]`. This makes the proof as a whole incorrect in an important way.